# Coordinate webtests in loadtests in vs2013

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

I am developing a load test in visual studio 2013. I build the load test from web performance tests and have each web performance test load data with a web test plugin the data goes into the context parameters. The web test plugin seems to work (if I throw exceptions in it, the test fails) during the load test. However, in examining the results it is clear that the data is not loaded or at least not used. Also in its behavior it is clear that not all data is available: failure due to missing data. When run within a wrapper web performance test, the web tests I use in the load test all work as expected.

So, my questions are aimed at people with more loadtest experience than I have.

- Is there indeed a difference between loadtest context parameters and webtest context parameters within that load test?
- How would I go about if I want to load data for each webtest within my load test to update the context parameters in the loadtest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a difference between WebTest and LoadTest context , they are indeed different concrete objects (WebTestContextClass, LoadTestContext).
2. What do you mean update the context parameters ? do you want one test to update the context parameters so it will be accessible from another? that is a wrong way to solve your problem IMO, If you need to preserve data or add logic to your tests I always use code I write by myself to run in the background and synchronize data/timing etc.